# Let's get critical: Mar 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Russian Language Stack Exchange](http://russian.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://russian.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Final Results

- [How to pronounce лёгкий](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/4103/how-to-pronounce-%d0%bb%d1%91%d0%b3%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [What's the Russian for "Industry professional"?](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/4147/whats-the-russian-for-industry-professional)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [What does водолазовой mean?](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/3060/what-does-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9-mean)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How to translate on Russian "towelheads"?](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/4083/how-to-translate-on-russian-towelheads)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How to translate LOGIN and REGISTER?](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/4106/how-to-translate-login-and-register)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [What is the difference between ‘Что нового?’, ‘Что новое?’ and ‘Чего нового?’](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/4166/what-is-the-difference-between-%e2%80%98%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be%e2%80%99-%e2%80%98%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b5%e2%80%99-and-%e2%80%98%d0%a7%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be%e2%80%99)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [What's the difference between "проходит" and "переходит"](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/3082/whats-the-difference-between-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82-and-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [What does 'я ухажеру бороду отбила' mean?](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/3077/what-does-%d1%8f-%d1%83%d1%85%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%83-%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%83-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b0-mean)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Idiomatic equivalent of « H/T » (hat tip) to credit in a tweet?](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/3080/idiomatic-equivalent-of-%c2%ab-h-t-%c2%bb-hat-tip-to-credit-in-a-tweet)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [What is true translation of CCCP - Cryptographic Computational Continuation Passing?](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/4097/what-is-true-translation-of-cccp-cryptographic-computational-continuation-pass)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

Answer (score 1):

I just want to say that the majority of questions and answers are of a much higher quality than they used to be a year ago. I think we're getting better!